# A "Whoever vs Whomever" usage puzzling example

Tags: grammar, pronouns

In her famous Blue Book of Grammar and Punctuation and at the [grammarbook.com site](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/whoever.asp), Jane Straus gives the following examples and brief explanations of the use of *whoever* and *whomever*:

> 1.Give it to whoever/whomever asks for it first.
>
> He asks for it first. Therefore, *whoever* is correct.
>
> 2.We will hire whoever/whomever you recommend.
>
> You recommend him. Therefore, *whomever* is correct.
>
> 3.We will hire whoever/whomever is most qualified.
>
> He is most qualified. Therefore, *whoever* is correct.

On reading this, I tried to come up with more complicated  situations, and here is the one which puzzled me:

> My dad said: Give the money to whoever/whomever who  you are sure
>   can't get by without it.

My speculation: My next door neighbors need the money badly and I'm sure they can't get by without it. So I give it to *them*. Therefore, *whomever* is correct.

> My dad said: Give the money to  whoever/whomever who you are sure
>   can't get by without it.

My speculation:They need the money badly, and I'm sure that it's "they" who can't get by without it. So I give the money to those *who* can't get by without it. Therefore, *whoever* is correct.

But can it really be that the both sentences are correct? I doubt that. There must be a flaw in my speculations. Where is it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BillJ *Sure* isn't a verb but an adjective, so it doesn't take an object. The relativizer represents the subject of sure's (reduced) complement *sure [that] _ want it*: you're sure that **they** want it. So the relativizer takes the subject case, *whoever*.

Comment: @BillJ 'sOK -- I've been wrestling with an answer to this and have succeeded in confusing myself entirely! The really gnarly question is what do you with this?  *Give it to ???ever you want to have it?*, where the subject of *have* is 'raised' to object of *want*. You desire that **he** should have it, but you want **him** to have it.

Comment: First, you don’t need the word “who” after “whoever/whomever”, since they already mean “the person who/whom”. The answer is that the function of the relativised element here is subject of the embedded _that_- clause (which is functioning as complement of the adjective “sure”), so subjective case “whoever” is correct; think of it as _you are sure (that) __ can’t get by without it_, where gap represents “the person”.

Comment: @BillJ I've raised the raising question (or I'm raising the raised question) on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/332576/24489).

Comment: @StoneyB Please, it's beer o'clock here, which probably explains my earlier lapse!

Comment: I've popped in an answer in ELU. Now for that beer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to apply the rules she gives.

Since the entire whoever/whomever clause is not the subject of a verb that follows it, we cannot apply rule 2. We look to rule 1.

Rule 1 says that the presence of whoever/whomever indicates a dependent clause. This is that clause

> whoever/whomever you are sure can't get by without it

Whoever/whomever must agree with the verb in that dependent clause, regardless of the rest of the sentence.

> whoever/whomever <strike>you are sure</strike> can't get by without it

I remove "you are sure" because it does not affect subject-verb agreement because *you* are not the one who can or cannot get by with out the money.

> whoever/whomever can't get by without it

I apply the he/him rule.

> he can't get by without it.

He = whoever, so I believe the answer is *whoever*,.

Comment: Convoluted, but correct conclusion! The relative _wh_- word represents the **subject** of the embedded complement clause, and subject pronouns of finite clauses are always subjective case of course.

Comment: I had to use the rules given in OP's text since he referenced it. I cannot assume he/she knows concepts outside of the referenced page like relativized, complement clause, etc. I don't even know what those mean. So although my answer could be shortened using those specialized terms, it's not useful to OP if  OP doesn't know what I'm talking about. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: @probablyme: Please rest assured that to me, the OP, your answer is crystal  clear and I upvoted it. Thanks ever so much.

Comment: @Rompey. That's great, but do you understand it grammatically, because that is crucial to having a good understanding of relative clauses?

Comment: @BillJ I think I do understand or rather I am close to understanding and I'm eager to read the answers to StoneyB's latest question on ELU. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Rompey. Ah, StoneyB's question on ELU is somewhat different because it raises a slightly tricky thing called "raising". But please do take a look as it is interesting.